# How can I convert a one element string into a char?

Tags: string, rust, char

I need to convert a one element `&str` into `char`. I was able to come up with this solution that also works for `String`:

```
fn main() {
    let comma: &str = ",";
    let my_char = comma.chars().nth(0).unwrap();
   
    assert_eq!(my_char, ',');
}
```

Is there a better or shorter way to do it?

Comment: Too bad https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_at is unstable…

Comment: @minitech, Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No huge improvements I can think of, but a few notes:

- You could replace `.nth(0)` with `.next()`, which does basically the same thing.
- You should ideally not use `.unwrap()`, since if the string is empty, your program will panic.
- If you really *must* panic, ideally use `.expect("msg")`, which will give users a better idea of *why* you panicked.

Taking those together:

```rust
fn main() {
    let comma: &str = ",";
    let my_char = comma.chars().next().expect("string is empty");

    assert_eq!(my_char, ',');
}
```

The only other thing to note is that "one element" is a somewhat dangerous thing to talk about.  For example, `"é"` has one `char`, but `"é"` *has two* (the first is a pre-composed U+00E9, whilst the second is a regular `e` followed by a U+0301 combining ◌́).